# CSS class for span inside a inside p

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have such a  structure of HTML:

```
<p>
    <a href="#">
        <span class = "class-for-span"> SOME TEXT HERE </span>
    </a>
</p>
```

and CSS:

```
p a{
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.class-for-span {
    color: red;
    text-decoretion: none;
}

.class-for-span:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

I want to get somethink like this:

For every a inside p i need grey underlined link. If there is span into a tag it must be red without decoration, and red underlined when its hover.

Now I have grey underlined link, if span inside a tag - red link with grey underline and red link with red udnerline when it's hover.

How can i solve my problem only with css? I've been trying also something like this:

```
p a span .class-for-span {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

but it's not working too...

Comment: There is a typo for `text-decoration` attribute in your `class-for-span` class

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/qULTP/

Comment: @mattytommo no, I mean like this: p a{
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: underline;
}


.class-for-span {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color: red;
}

but I can't change p a {} style.

Answer (score 4):

```
p a span .class-for-span {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Won't work because of the space between `span` and `.class-...`. That would imply "the element with class `class-...` **within** the span". You can't overwrite an element's parent's property in CSS. The solution would be to set `text-decoration:none;` on the `a` tag and only use it on the `span`:

```
p a { text-decoration:none; }
p a span.class-for-span { text-decoration:none; }
p a:hover span.class-for-span { text-decoration:underline; }
```

This will cause the underline to appear when the anchor is hovered over, but not necessarily when the span is hovered over. So the underline would still appear on the span even if you had:

```
<a href="..."><span>Text</span><img src="..." alt="" /></a>
```

...and hovered over the image.

Comment: It still seems to work not properly. A tag without span inside is not underlined.

Comment: The problem is that there is no CSS parent selector. You can't say "if this element exists inside parent, style parent differently". What you could do is add the class to the anchor, rather than the span: `<a class="class-for-span"><span>Blah</span></a>` then style with: `a.class-for-span { text-decoration:none; }` `a.class-for-span:hover { text-decoration:underline; }`

Comment: I know, but the problem is that I'm working with some kind of CMS, I want to customize one of components, and styling text in rich text editor just adds span around this text with proper class. When I add style to normal <p> it works, but when i want to style <a> it just add <span> inside <a>. I know there are ways to add this using jQuery for example, but I just can't do this in this project.

Answer (score 1):

the a element is what is being underlined, not the span, so when you remove the underline from the span, you still have the a element keeping its underline. make your original block

```
p a span {
color: grey;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

and everything should begin to work

Comment: However, span style is not overwritten by a-tag style, it looks like it's seen anyway. What more, I need text-decoretion: none; for p a span

Answer (score 1):

```
p a:link, p a:hover, p a:active, p a:visited {
  /* works for any 'a' tag inside a 'p' tag */
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #CCCCCC;
}
```

that will work for these:

```
<p><a href="#">Hello</a><br>
<a href="#">Hello again</a></p>
```